# Download application/octet-stream

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I'm trying to type wrong URL of my website an application/octet-stream  is downloaded.
for example URL is
**`www.example.com/example/example`** 
this is right url and works properly but when I write url like
 **`www.example.com/example/exa`** or like **`www.example.com/exa`**

then an  **application/octet-stream** is downloaded. 
Any one tell me why this is happening and give me solution.
I'm using a PHP website.

Comment: Can you provide this code snippet?

Comment: Update this in your question by editing it.